# Cant find the Scroll View property to know how many pixels the scroll view did scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a scroll view with a label in it, and I wants after someones scroll the label X px's to the right and release his finger to delete this label with animation.

So I created a delegate connection and added the scroll view delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSLog(@"scroll view did scroll");
}
```

In this method I want to say something like:

```
if myScrollView.someProperty moved X px's to the right and the user pulled his finger 

delete this label sliding with animation to the right
```

Can someone please help out here :/

tnx ahead!!

Comment: maybe scrool.contentOffset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check UIScrollView's contentOffset property:

```
contentOffset - The point at which the origin of the content view is offset 
from the origin of the scroll view.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use UISwipeGestureRecognizer to do this and define how many pixel you want to drag the label to the right. You can try the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mylabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [mylabel sizeToFit];
    [mylabel addGestureRecognizer:[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeLabel:)]];

}

- (void)didSwipeLabel:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipe
{
    NSLog(@"swipe");

    swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            // swipe the label 50px right
           mylabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(50.0, 0.0);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // when animation
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                 NSLog(@"label should be removed");
                [mylabel removeFromSuperview];
            }];
        }];




    }
}
```